# Why doesn't my systemd startup script run?

Tags: service, startup, systemd

I'm trying to run a trivial script at bootup on my debian testing machine.  I followed a few guides, but the services do not start.  Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?  I'd like to understand systemd before I start whining about it on the internet.

I created `/etc/systemd/system/startup-scripts.service` (sometimes here, sometimes as a symlinks to /lib/systemd/system/my-file.service) and wrote

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync date at boot up

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startup-script.sh
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then ran

```
sudo systemctl enable startup-scripts.service
```

I also filed out /usr/bin/startup-script.sh, made it executable, and ran it.  As far as I could tell the script would run, but my reboots have been fruitless.

I'm guessing the answer will involve journalctl.  Not really sure what I'm looking at here.  I also wouldn't be surprised if multi-user is the wrong target.  It was the most reasonable looking one, but I'm not really confident about what it's for.

Comment: Based n your description, it seems you want it to be a type=oneshot, not a type=simple. But why bother reinventing the wheel when you can install ntpd and ntpdate? The ntpdate.service will do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Don't call external scripts that do a bunch of stuff. Create one unit for each service you want to start or run.

Comment: Are you able to start the service ?? Run `systemctl start startup-scripts.service` and then do `systemctl status startup-scripts.service` the service should be running by then.